# ng-repeate images, an empty image not found, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of images, if i use ng-repeat, an jQuery error will apeare for 
`GET http:// SOME IP :8001/%7B%7Bimage%7D%7D 404 (NOT FOUND)`

It seems that ng-repeate creates an empty image? But in the console.log there are no empty entries...

controller:

```
appControllers.controller('remindersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http){
    console.log("reminders controller heyo");

    var staticImgPath = "static/img/pages/reminders/"
    $scope.reminderWastesTypes = [
        staticImgPath + 'Biolski-odpadki.png',
        staticImgPath + 'Embalaza.png',
        staticImgPath + 'Ostali-odpadki.png',
        staticImgPath + 'Papir.png',
        staticImgPath + 'Steklo.png',
    ];

}]);
```

html

```
        <ul rn-carousel class="image"  rn-carousel-control attribute>
            <li data-ng-repeat="image in reminderWastesTypes">
                <img src="{{image}}">
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using ng-src, instead of src. 
More details [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc)